# How to construct an "excel-friendly" string in MATLAB?

Tags: string, excel, matlab, clipboard

I want to construct a table as follows:

```
Feature  |   F-score   |   Precision  |   Recall    |
Feature1 | 0.81 (0.82) |  0.83 (0.84) | 0.85 (0.86) |
Feature2 | 0.87 (0.88) |  0.83 (0.84) | 0.85 (0.86) |
.. etc
```

(the `|` character just represents a new column, not required in the string)

I just need to construct the "inner" part, i.e. the part just with numbers as a string and copy it to clipboard, so that I can go to Excel and paste the whole thing at once. Is this possible? If so, I would appreciate a working example.

### What I have tried so far:

I tried to construct the string as follows:

```
str = [num2str(fscore1,2) ' (' num2str(fscore2,2) ')\t etc'];
```

Apparently `'\t'` is not working for my purpose. Also I have no idea how to copy the string to clipboard automatically. So any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary issue with what you're trying to do is that simple string concatenation (using `[]` or `strcat`) treats `\t` as a string literal (the character `\` followed by the character `t`) rather than a control sequence. Instead you'll want to use either `sprintf` or `fprintf` or `char(9)` (9 is ASCII for tab) to have tab characters.

```
% The way that you tried
['a\t', 'b'];
% 'a\tb'

% The way that it should be
sprintf('a\tb')
%  a    b

% Or using char(9)
['a', char(9), 'b']
%  a    b
```

For an "Excel-friendly" string, you want to use some delimiter between your values in a row (probably tabs is easiest) and then a newline character between rows. We can construct such a string easily using `sprintf` (see code snippet below).

As far as automatically copying something to the clipboard, the built-in [`clipboard`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/clipboard.html) function allows you to copy a string to the system clipboard. You can construct a tab-delimited string from your data and store it within the clipboard. Then you can paste it into Excel (or any program).

You would need to construct your string similar to this:

```
% Labels for the columns
header = sprintf('%s\t', 'Feature', 'F-score', 'Precision', 'Recall');

% Store your data within a cell array
data = {'Feature1', 0.81, 0.82, 0.83, 0.84, 0.85, 0.86;
    'Feature2', 0.87, 0.88, 0.83, 0.84, 0.85, 0.86}.';

% Construct your tab-delimited string with newlines between rows
datastring = sprintf('%s\t%0.2f (%0.2f)\t%0.2f (%0.2f)\t%0.2f (%0.2f)\n', data{:});

% Append the header to the rest of the data
fullstring = sprintf('%s\n%s', header, datastring);

% Copy this string to the system clipboard
clipboard('copy', fullstring);
```

You can paste the result in Excel (or related programs) to yield something like this:

[image]

Another option is to place your data into a cell array which you can visualize using the Workspace variable editor. From the workspace viewer, you can copy the contents (just like you would in Excel) and paste them into any program.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer.